# CouchDB v1.7.1 database replication to CouchDB v2.3.0 database fails

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

In Fauxton, I've setup a replication rule from a CouchDB v1.7.1 database to a new CouchDB v2.3.0 database.

The source does not have any authentication configured. The target does. I've added the username and password to the Job Configuration.

It looks like the replication got stuck somewhere in the process. 283.8 KB (433 documents) are present in the new database. The source contains about 18.7 MB (7215 docs) of data.

When restarting the database, I'm always getting the following error:

> [error] 2019-02-17T17:29:45.959000Z nonode@nohost <0.602.0> --------
>   throw:{unauthorized,<<"unauthorized to access or create database
>   http://my-website.com/target-database-name/">>}: 
>   Replication 5b4ee9ddc57bcad01e549ce43f5e31bc+continuous failed to
>   start "https://my-website.com/source-database-name/ "
>   -> "http://my-website.com/target-database-name/ " doc
>   <<"shards/00000000-1fffffff/_replicator.1550593615">>:<<"1e498a86ba8e3349692cc1c51a00037a">>
>   stack:[{couch_replicator_api_wrap,db_open,4,[{file,"src/couch_replicator_api_wrap.erl"},{line,114}]},{couch_replicator_scheduler_job,init_state,1,[{file,"src/couch_replicator_scheduler_job.erl"},{line,584}]}]

I'm not sure what is going on here. From the logs I understand there's an authorization issue. But the database is already present (hence, it has been replicated partially already).

What does this error mean and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the CouchDB v2.3.0 instance was being re-initialized on reboot. It required me to fill-in the cluster configuration again.

Therefore, the replication could not continue until I had the configuration re-applied.

The issue with having to re-apply the cluster configuration has been solved in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781670/setup-apache-couchdb-screen-re-appears-on-container-restart).